# ActionBar setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false) is not working on android 2.3

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-progressbar

The setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false) is not working for 2.3 android.
I'm using the code below.The progress bar is show always and is not hidden. 
The same code is working on android 4.x and the progress bar is hidden. The activity is 
extending from SherlockFragmentActivity, and there is no call like setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true); that will make the progress bar visible.
My complete code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ((SherlockFragmentActivity) JbActivity.this)
            .requestWindowFeature((long) com.actionbarsherlock.view.Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    restart = false;
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (SelectedItems.isNull()) {
        restart = true;
        try {
            String jsonString = savedInstanceState
                    .getString("SelectedItems");
            SelectedItems.build(jsonString);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(JbActivity.this,CityList.class);
            mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(mainIntent);
            finish();
        }
    }

}
```

There is no place in the code where I call 
Can you please suggest a way so I can hide the progress bar on android 2.x. Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using : 
`getSherlockActivity().setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);`

If you are calling it from a `SherlockFragment` or just :

```
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,Im calling from activity that extends SherlockFragmentActivity in the OnCreate() method. So there is no method getSherlockActivity(), I tried getSherlock().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false); and setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false); but no luck

Comment: First of all, post some more code what are you doing after the given code..if you have some code where you are showing the progress bar again...and basically what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Actualy your answer was correct setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false); seams to work, thanks

Comment: Wups, I always forget to use the support call vs the regular call.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this method to display:

```
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

and this method to hide:

```
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
```

Both work for me on android 2.3.3 to 4.1.7

Answer (score 0):

Just call

```
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
```

**after** setContentView